# .htaccess redirect to error page if port is not 80

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, port

I'm running a [portable server](http://www.server2go-web.de/) through usb stick. The thing is I also have WAMP installed in my local machine and Apache somehow gets started on windows startup, because of some random reason which I don't recall now and it can't be changed. I want to **prepare** my portable server in situations like this, so closing httpd.exe from process and starting my portable server is not an option. Anyway, because of already active httpd.exe my portable server's WordPress site can only be accessed through localhost:81 - this is a problem as WP site is very dependent on the URL and I don't want to include the url with port on WP database.

Here is what I want to do through .htaccess:

- On any path except for error.php file check if not port 80
- If not port 80 redirect to /error.php?code=port

It it possible for it to have priority over WP redirection or URL handling?

In the error.php I provided info on how to manually close httpd.exe and such so my family and friends can access the portable site. It's sort of like a gallery and calender  application for events and other such stuff...

Please help? I'm I can't figure it out at all. I know others may not have apache already running, but I want to prepare for such a situation.

Something like the following, but the following doesn't work.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <If "%{SERVER_PORT} = 80">
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </If>
    <Else>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(error.php)($|/) - [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /error.php?code=port [L]
    </Else>
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#  <If "%{SERVER_PORT} = 80">
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond  %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$ 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond  %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
#</If>
#<Else>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond  %{SERVER_PORT} !^80$ 
RewriteRule ^(error.php)($|/) - [L]
RewriteCond  %{SERVER_PORT} !^80$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /error.php?code=port [L]
#</Else>
```

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for... but it's not working though. When gone to sample.local:81 it keeps on loading on an infinite-like loading and then goes to a blank sample.local. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this apache config

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond  %{SERVER_PORT} !^80$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%{SERVER_NAME}:80%{REQUEST_URI} 

RewriteCond  %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$ 
RewriteRule .* http://example.com/index.php [L]
```

The 1st paragraph redirects if its NOT 80

the 2nd is just an alternative you can try, if you want only that matches 80

for more info on rewrites,
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Please refer to original post, I put in more details.

Comment: I think its better NOT to touch and modify the htaccess of wordpress coz some plugins (w3totalcache,others) and wp itself checks/validates its rewrite/htaccess. You might get some issue upon upgrading your wordpress or on its permalinks settings. Let me re-create your situation on my localhost and I'll update my answer afterwards

Comment: @fedmich It's perfectly reasonable to modify the htaccess of a WordPress site

Answer (score 0):

[VirtualHosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html) are what you are looking for.

A small example of how you can achieve `http://wplocal/` **or** `http://wp.local/` to point to `/var/www/wp` AND `http://localhost/` **or** `http://http.local` to point to `/another/root/path`.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin wp@you.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/wp"
    ServerName wplocal
    ServerAlias wp.local
    ErrorLog "/somepath/here"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin you@you.com
    DocumentRoot "/another/root/path"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias http.local
    ErrorLog "/logs/path"
</VirtualHost>
```

See [this](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/apache-virtual-host/) for cool images that explain that stuff.

Hope that helped.

Comment: Please refer to original post, I put in more details. Server2Go automatically generates vhosts and changes ports.