# How to redirect a domain to a different IP if accessed by a specific port?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, networking, dns, ip

I was wondering how I could redirect a sub domain I own (such as mydomain.dx.am) to another external IP address it is accessed by a specific port.

in other words, if you type in this domain, it takes you to the hosted website that is directly attached to the domain (the host is AwardSpace). However, if you access this domain through a specific port (such as 25565 through minecraft), it redirects you to a different external IP (XX.XX.XX.XX). I have tried other services (like NO-IP and free ones), but they don't work for **SUBDOMAINS** that you already **OWN** and for redirection only on **SPECIFIC PORTS**.

I don't want all ports of the subdomain to redirect to a diffferent external IP address, just 1 specific port

Is there any online service or specific way of doing this? What could I do to the .htaccess file to create this redirect?

I have access to the files of the site/host, and to the .htaccess (directly on the file or automated through the host). I can't seem to find acccess to the DNS Zone file and changing the nameservers is really glitchy and fails most of the time for an unaquired reason...if there is some way to do this with what I have avaliable then please let me know! Thanks!

Here is my current .htaccess file (has no problems):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Do you have access to create/modify vhosts?

Comment: No, sadly, I don't think there's a way to create virtual hosts, the closest thing would be creating VPS Servers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will allow you to redirect based on the incoming port, but assumes that apache is listening on all ports (replace {PORT} with the port you want to have redirected):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond  %{SERVER_PORT} ^{PORT}$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.redirect.com [L, R=301]
```

Answer partially pulled from [.htaccess redirect to error page if port is not 80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12540539/htaccess-redirect-to-error-page-if-port-is-not-80)

Comment: You should post the contents of your htaccess file then and describe what about it isn't working

Comment: where in the .htaccess file would I put this? Do I have to replace {SERVER_PORT} with anything? Will this conflict with the current contents of the file?

Comment: Nope, leave that section alone.  Place this just after the `<ifmodule>` node in your .htaccess of the subdomain you're interested in having redirected if the port matches

Comment: My .htaccess looks like this now: [.htaccess file](http://pastebin.com/JeT32ZQ6), but now the redirect doesn't work (says can't connect to server) and the site itself gives an Error 500

Comment: Here's the 500 error: http://pastebin.com/5Q2jgqXd. I can't seem to find the server error logs that it states...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99252/discussion-between-evan-and-abob78).